# Jquery : Popover onclick event

Tags: jquery, html, css, popup

I have stuck with this point , to show the particular div of HTMl in onclick of hyperlink  in Jquery, I have tried the following code and didnt get answer,

```
$(function() {
    var moveLeft = 20;
    var moveDown = 10;

    $('a#trigger').click(function(e) {
        $('div#pop-up').show()
            .css('top', e.pageY + moveDown)
            .css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft)
            .appendTo('body');
        }, function() {
            $('div#pop-up').hide();
    });
    $('a#trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
        $("div#pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
    });
});
```

Here I have tried `hover()` method , instead of `click()` method ,its working when i put `click()` It wont,but I need `click()` method to work , How  do I acheive it?  please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because UNLIKE hover(), the click() method supports a single handler only.**
See this: **http://api.jquery.com/click/**

So in your case, notice the code fragment:

```
                $('a#trigger').click(function(e) {
                    $('div#pop-up').show()
                    .css('top', e.pageY + moveDown)
                    .css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft)
                    .appendTo('body');
                }, function() {
                    $('div#pop-up').hide();
                });
```

The first function, which you intend to execute on click, **is actually being passed as meaningless event data**. **Everytime you are clicking a#trigger, it's the second function which is being executed.**

You could alternately code it like this:

```
var triggerState = 0;
$('a#trigger').click(function(e) {
    if (triggerState === 0) {
        $('div#pop-up').show()
        .css('top', e.pageY + moveDown)
        .css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft)
        .appendTo('body');
        triggerState = 1;
    }
    else if (triggerState === 1) {
        $('div#pop-up').hide();
        triggerState = 0;
    }
});
```

I think you made the mistake of thinking that click, like hover, accepts two functions for the differing states - unfortunately no - mouseover and mouseout are unambiguously state trackable, however, "alternate clicks" are not unambiguously state trackable, hence jQuery click doesn't offer this facility.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    var moveLeft = 20;
    var moveDown = 10;

    $('a#trigger').click(function(e) {

        if($('div#pop-up').length)
        {
            $('div#pop-up').toggle();
        }
        else
        {
             $('div#pop-up')
                .css({'top': e.pageY + moveDown,'left': e.pageX + moveLeft})
                .appendTo('body').show();
        }
    });

    $('a#trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
        $("div#pop-up").css({'top': e.pageY + moveDown,'left': e.pageX + moveLeft});
    });
});
```

Comment: Check `div#pop-up` is created in `body` or not? Or try the above answer I changed

Comment: it is present , I had check this for  hover() function already.